# How to manage hosted fonts in my website using postcss?

Tags: css, fonts, gulp, font-face, postcss

I'm new in gulp and I have a problem with managing hosted fonts in my website.
Does anyone know how I should write gulp task, which creates `@fontface` in my `style.css` file? (I tried to use this npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-font-magician#hosted) but it didn't work!)

here is my gulp task (styles.js):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
nested = require('postcss-nested'),
cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
mixins = require('postcss-mixins'),
hexrgba = require('postcss-hexrgba'),
colorFunctions = require('postcss-color-function'),
fontMagician = require('postcss-font-magician')({
    hosted: ['../../app/assets/fonts']
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, mixins, cssvars, nested, hexrgba, colorFunctions, 
     fontMagician, autoprefixer]))
    .on('error', function(errorInfo) {
      console.log(errorInfo.toString());
      this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles'));
});
```

here is my css code:

```
body {
    font-family: 'parastoo';
}
```

and this is my source tree:

```
|--app
|  |-- assets
|  |  |-- fonts
|  |  |   |-- parastoo.woff
|  |  |   |-- parastoo.woff2
|  |-- index.html
|-- gulp
|  |-- tasks
|  |  |-- styles.js
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- package.json
|-- webpack.config.js
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you confirm that your paths are correct? Note the difference here : `hosted: ['../../app/assets/fonts']` and `gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')`

Comment: Fonts path shouldn't be `./app/assets/fonts`? I believe the path must to be relative from `gulpfile.js` file and not from tasks files.